# Plus parameter to R script

Tags: r

I have made a pretty big package in R and I have collected a lot of smaller scripts in it. Later on it turned out that I may need to configure it a bit more than what I have made. Here is an example:

```
analyse <- function(param1,param2,param3,...){
   
function1 <- function(param1,param2,param3){...}
function2 <- function(param1,param2,param3){...}
function3 <- function(param1,param2,param3){...}

}
```

As you can see, this function have 3 function inside, and all of them have their parameters. When I call it:

```
analyse(param1=value1, param2=value2, param3=value3)
```

My question is, that is it possible to pass parameters to the inner functions as well? And what if the inner functions share a similar name parameter. For example function1 and 2 have the parameter name maxLength and I would like function1 to be maxLength=2 and function2 to be maxLength=10.

I would imagine it like this when calling:

```
analyse(param1=value1, param2=value2, param3=value3, paramToInnerFunct1=value1, paramToInnerFunct3=value1)
```

In my case if I give a plus parameter what would go to an inner function to the calling nothing happens.

Is there a way to deal with my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

the simple solution is to just add the additional parameters like this:

```
analyse <- function(param1,param2,param3,
                    paramToInnerFunct1,paramToInnerFunct3,...){

function1 <- function(param1,param2,param3,paramToInnerFunct1){...}
function2 <- function(param1,param2,param3){...}
function3 <- function(param1,param2,param3,paramToInnerFunct3){...}

}
```

Edit:
maybe it works without named arguments (...) in your function 'analyse', but you would need the arguments in your 'function1'... though like this:

```
analyse <- function(param1,param2,param3,...){

function1 <- function(param1,param2,param3,paramToInnerFunct1){...}
function2 <- function(param1,param2,param3){...}
function3 <- function(param1,param2,param3,paramToInnerFunct3){...}

}
```

Another idea:
if you define the additional arguments like 'paramToInnerFunct1' in your global environment, you still can use them within the 'function1' like:

```
paramToInnerFunct1 <- "whatever object goes here"
function1 <- function(param1,param2,param3){
    # use paramToInnerFunct1 from your global environment here
}
```

Hope that helps,
Samuel

Comment: Yes that's a pretty straight forward solution. I thought about it, but it it would take so much params from the inner functions. Imagine like this: you have a function with its default params, but the after the `...` you can give additional params to it. For example if the function contains parts from ggplot, for the design, you can modify the ggplot part of the function even with no parameters provided default to the original function.

Comment: extended my answer with 2 more options

Comment: I see! Thank you! To sum up, basically it is impossible to just give extra parameters to a function except if I predefine it in the main functions environment.